# Hide toolbar behaviour like medium android application

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to achieve this effect (like medium android app toolbar), I want to hide a custom view, unfortunately I am not able to do. This is my layout.

https://i.ibb.co/KNp1zfV/2019-05-27-14-23-47.gif

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/filtersContainerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/left_rectangle_edge_view_size"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_rectangle_ripple_background"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_padding_extra_small"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/resultMessageTextView"
            style="@style/DefaultTextStyle.Black"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/separator_gray"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_pencil_edit"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/default_margin_small"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/default_margin_medium"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/default_padding"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/default_padding_large"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_padding"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Searching for family medicine near Montevideo" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/filtersHeaderTextView"
            style="@style/DefaultTextStyle.Black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_margin_medium"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin_extra_small"
            android:text="@string/filters"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/resultMessageTextView" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/expandCollapseFilterOptionsImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?actionBarItemBackground"
            android:padding="@dimen/default_margin_small"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/filtersHeaderTextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/filtersHeaderTextView"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
            app:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/filtersButtonsLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_margin_small"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/filtersHeaderTextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/expandCollapseFilterOptionsImageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/filtersHeaderTextView"
            tools:visibility="visible">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/applyFilterButton"
                style="@style/SmallTextStyle.Bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/default_padding_small"
                android:text="@string/apply"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector_primary_dark" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/clearFiltersButton"
                style="@style/SmallTextStyle.Bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_margin_small"
                android:padding="@dimen/default_padding_small"
                android:text="@string/clear"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector_primary_dark" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/topSeparatorView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/separator_height"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/left_rectangle_edge_view_size"
        android:background="@color/separator_gray"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="snap" />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/resultContainerScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/providersResultRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/providers_result_margin_start"
            android:overScrollMode="never" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

> *[This thread on medium](https://medium.com/martinomburajr/android-design-collapsing-toolbar-scrollflags-e1d8a05dcb02) might serve exactly what you need, and here's [another one](https://medium.com/martinomburajr/android-design-coordinator-layout-2-creating-custom-behaviors-3b54b387c08b)  if you want to dig deeper in the custom behaviors*

*Now to the answer:*

**1. main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- call the content xml file-->
    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**1. content_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="hello world"/>

            <!-- your content goes here-->

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**3. Important note**

> - **content_main.xml use :**  `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` **instead** of `ScrollView`.
> - **use** `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` **inside** `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` like below.
> - **if** and **only** **if** you migrated to `AndroidX` make sure to change the design support library, if you still using `android.support` keep everything as it is.

**UPDATE**

*Try the following changes:*

**1.** add this to your `ToolBar`

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
```

**2.** add this to your `NestedScrollLayout`

```
android:fillViewport="true"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried this, but is not the same effect, with the scroll flags the toolbar is hide according to the offset, I dont want this, I want to hide the toolbar immediately.